# Execute file .sql from NodeJs - SQL Server

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server

SQL File

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SP_NotasEstudiantesMateria_G]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_NotasEstudiantesMateria_G] AS' 
END
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Arlington
-- Create date: 04-11-2018
-- Description: Trae las notas de los estudiantes de determinado curso en determinado año y de determinada materia
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Arlington
-- Create date: 16-06-2019
-- Description: Se agrega logica para manejar las ausencias
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Arlington
-- Create date: 19-06-2019
-- Description: Se quita join con la tabla adinasistencias
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Arlington
-- Create date: 19-06-2019
-- Description: test sdf kjsdfk ndskgn fskdnkn
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_NotasEstudiantesMateria_G]

    @pIdAñoLectivo INT,
    @pIdCurso INT,
    @pIdMateria INT,
    @pIdMaestro BIGINT      

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE 
    @IdAñoLectivo INT = @pIdAñoLectivo, 
    @IdCurso INT = @pIdCurso,
    @IdMaestro INT = @pIdMaestro,
    @IdMateria BIGINT = @pIdMateria

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT MC.Sec AS SecMatCurso, ET.IdTercero, CONCAT(ET.Papellido,' ',ET.Sapellido,' ',ET.Pnombre,' ',ET.Snombre) AS NombreComp 
        , MR.Sec AS IdMateria, MR.NomMateria, MT.Sec AS IdMatricula, P1, 
        (SELECT CantInasistencias 
        FROM ADInasistencia 
        WHERE IdEstudiante = ET.IdTercero 
        AND IdCurso = @IdCurso
        AND IdMateria = @IdMateria
        AND IdPeriodo = 1) AS IAP1, P2, (SELECT CantInasistencias 
        FROM ADInasistencia 
        WHERE IdEstudiante = ET.IdTercero 
        AND IdCurso = @IdCurso
        AND IdMateria = @IdMateria
        AND IdPeriodo = 2) IAP2, P3, (SELECT CantInasistencias 
        FROM ADInasistencia 
        WHERE IdEstudiante = ET.IdTercero
        AND IdCurso = @IdCurso
        AND IdMateria = @IdMateria
        AND IdPeriodo = 3)IAP3, P4, (SELECT CantInasistencias 
        FROM ADInasistencia 
        WHERE IdEstudiante = ET.IdTercero 
        AND IdCurso = @IdCurso
        AND IdMateria = @IdMateria
        AND IdPeriodo = 4)IAP4,  ((P1 + P2 + P3 + P4) / 4) AS Prom   
        FROM ADTerceros ET 
        INNER JOIN ADMatriculas MT ON ET.IdTercero = MT.IdEstudiante AND MT.IdAñoLectivo = @IdAñoLectivo
        INNER JOIN ADCursos CS ON MT.IdCurso = CS.Sec
        INNER JOIN ADMateriasCursos MC ON CS.Sec = MC.IdCurso
        INNER JOIN ADMaterias MR ON MC.IdMateria = MR.Sec
        LEFT JOIN ADNotas NT ON MC.Sec = NT.SecMatCurso AND NT.IdEstudiante = ET.IdTercero AND NT.IdMatricula = MT.Sec
        WHERE CS.Sec = @IdCurso AND MR.Sec = @IdMateria AND MC.IdMaestro = @IdMaestro AND MT.Cancelada = 0 ORDER BY NombreComp
END
```

Error response

[image]

Code JS

```
const sql = require('mssql');
var text = fs.readFileSync("./testsql.sql", "utf-8");

sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    const request = new sql.Request()
    request.batch(text, (err, result) => {
        return res.status(200).json({
            result: (err)? err: result
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Despite being smudgy and blurry (please post textual responses as *text*) the error is pretty clear: Declare that variable. Are you declaring it in terms of itself??

Comment: I have to wonder if that is the exact SQL you are trying to run, because in the SQL `@IdCurso` appears to be correctly declared.

Comment: Ok, the script is the same and if I run it directly in the database engine it works fine, the idea is to run a list of .sql documents.

Comment: @DaleK : Did you solve the issue? i am also facing the same issue.